# MySql query SUM from two tables group by month

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: tbl_job1 , tbl_job2 and tbl_users.

tbl_job1:

```
 ID| DataComplited | Profit | UserID |
 ===================================
 1 |  2017-01-01   | 100    |  1     |
 2 |  2017-02-01   | 200    |  1     |
 3 |  2017-03-01   | 150    |  1     |
 4 |  2017-01-01   | 400    |  2     |
 5 |  2017-01-01   | 120    |  1     |
 6 |  2017-02-03   |  30    |  1     |
```

tbl_job2:

```
 ID| DataComplited | Profit | UserID |
 ===================================
 1 |  2017-02-01   |  50    |  1     |
 2 |  2017-03-01   |  20    |  1     |
 3 |  2017-02-03   |  20    |  1     |
 4 |  2017-02-03   |  50    |  1     |
```

tbl_users:

```
 ID| fullname | 
 ==============
 1 |  Robert  |
 2 |  Maria   |
```

I want to see:

```
 Fullname | Year |  Month  |    Profit 1 |  Profit 2 |  Total |
 ==========================================================
  Maria   | 2017  |January | 400.00      |           |400.00  |
  Robert  | 2017  |January | 220.00      |           |220.00  |
          |       |February| 230.00      |  120.00   |350.00  |
          |       | March  | 150.00      |   20.00   |170.00  |
```

But I get:

```
     Fullname | Year |  Month | Profit 1 |  Profit 2 |  Total |
     ==========================================================
      Maria   |2017  |January | 400.00   |           |400.00  |
      Robert  |2017  |January | 220.00   |           |220.00  |
              |      |February| 260.00   |  120.00   |380.00  |
              |      | March  | 150.00   |   20.00   |170.00  |
```

Please see what Robert's got in February.
Sorry about my English,  I'm Russian. But I think you can see everything on those tables. Actually I want to  see sum from two jobs for every month.

I'm new on MySql, I tried this code:

```
 SELECT 
        year(tbl_job1.DataComplited) AS `Year`,
       DATE_FORMAT(tbl_job1.DataComplited, '%M') AS `Month`,
       DATE_FORMAT(tbl_job1.DataComplited, '%m') AS Month_ord,
       tbl_users.fullname,
       SUM(tbl_job1.Profit) AS Profit_1
       SUM(tbl_job2.Profit) AS Profit_2 ,
       (SUM(tbl_job1.profit)) + (SUM(COALESCE(tbl_job2.profit, 0))) AS Total
 FROM tbl_job1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_job2 ON tbl_job1.DataComplited = tbl_job2.DataComplited
 INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_job1.UserID = tbl_users.ID
 GROUP BY tbl_users.fullname,
         month(tbl_job1.DataComplited),
         DATE_FORMAT(`month`, '%m'),year
 ORDER BY tbl_users.fullname,
         year(tbl_job1.DataComplited),
         DATE_FORMAT(tbl_job1.DataComplited, '%M')
```

Please help me.

thank you, I but I decided by myself.

```html
SELECT
year(a.DataComplited) AS `Year`,
DATE_FORMAT(a.DataComplited, '%M') AS `Month`,
tbl_users.fullname,
SUM(a.Profit) AS Profit_1,
b.Profit AS Profit_2,
SUM(COALESCE(a.Profit, 0)) + COALESCE(b.Profit, 0) as Total
FROM tbl_job1 as a
INNER JOIN tbl_users ON a.UserID = tbl_users.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(DataComplited, '%M')  AS `Month`,
DataComplited,
SUM(COALESCE(tbl_job2.profit, 0)) AS Profit
FROM tbl_job2
GROUP BY month(DataComplited), DATE_FORMAT(`month`, '%m')
) AS b USING (DataComplited)
GROUP BY tbl_users.fullname,  month(a.DataComplited), DATE_FORMAT(`month`, '%m'), year
ORDER BY tbl_users.fullname, year(a.DataComplited), DATE_FORMAT(a.DataComplited, '%m')
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code